# Windows Authentication Server Role Verification

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, authentication, role

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.I am connected with Windows Authentication, I wanted to verify/check whether the Login had a sysadmin Server Role using code. Is there any script to verify the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to check you're login if its sysadmin or other users?

Comment: I have logged in using windows authentication. I want to check what Role does the Login has. Does it have a sysadmin role or any other role? If there was a script that could provide the same when logged in using windows authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin', 'login') = 1
```

This function will return 1 if the given login is a member of the given role, 0 otherwise.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176015.aspx

This is the way it's implemented in the system SPs that do anything requiring sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sp_helpsrvrolemember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188772.aspx)

```
EXEC sp_helpsrvrolemember 'sysadmin'
```

Or else you can query the catalog syslogin view:

```
SELECT NAME, isntname FROM SYSLOGINS
WHERE sysadmin = 1 and hasaccess = 1
```

Using GUI:

Open the  Management Studio. Connect to the SQL Server,  expand Security node, and expand Server Roles. From the list of Server Roles right click sysadmin and choose Properties. Here it will list down all the sysadmin logins for you.